# Select data from table using SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I have a table name "chat_details" I wanna access only data with green underline according to time, I use the following query

```
//suppose $user_id = 1;

"SELECT * 
FROM chat_details WHERE from_user_id='$user_id' OR to_user_id='$user_id' ORDER BY time DESC"
```

It fetch all the rows because all rows contain user_id = 1 in one of the column, but i need only green underline rows as compare to red one because green one are latest according to time(column), how can i fetch only these green underlines?

Comment: What do you mean, only fetch the "top one". Top one according to what metric?

Comment: What is the criteria to select the rows?

Comment: according to time(column)

Comment: You say "according to time", but you have 11-13, 11-26, and a whole slew in between. I'm confused how you even get to that avenue of green underlines

Comment: How do you specify that top group, as a "block"?

Comment: And why wouldn't the last row be selected?

Comment: $Ankit i have to use this in inbox, so i need sender name from to_user_id column, so when i select data i want to select only chat_details of user_id =1, with all user only once, so i need only 5 rows i.e row num 1, 2, 8, 12 and 15. but instead of doing this it fetch all the row where user_id =1 is present in both column.

Comment: @FrankerZ i need row num 1,2,8,12,n 15 for user id 1. and I didn't know the query and limitations

Comment: Would it be possible to help us with sample output ?

Comment: You're not telling us HOW you're getting the rows you need. Sample output I don't think would help here (As he told us the rows he wants are the underlined green ones), but we don't understand how you get the green underlines. Why do you only want THOSE rows? What make those rows different than the other. Look at it from a 3rd party: Tell me how I can differentiate those rows from the others.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @FrankerZ i edit the question so now you understand what i want to do, have a look please

Answer (score 0):

This is one posible query, that should solve your question.

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM chat_details c 
  WHERE (c.from_user_id='$user_id' OR c.to_user_id='$user_id') 
  AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM chat_details d 
        WHERE d.from_user_id = c.from_user_id 
        AND d.to_user_id = c.to_user_id 
        AND d.time > c.time)
  ORDER BY c.time DESC"
```

Actually I could not test, hope I haven't made a mistake.

The query selects all data as in your query, but only thoose which haven't a newer chat between the two users.
For the EXISTS keyword see http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-exists/